# How to make private bucket on AWS s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a **private** bucket on **AWS s3** and read and write to it from an Android App.

I found many of resources and questions but nothing of it gave me a complete answer.

I made a private one but don't know what should I write in Bucket Privacy, and what I need to access it from an Android app.

How can I do it?

**More details:**

My app is an e-commerce app has users, they upload photos to the app and view it from a website and from the app too.

All data on my server except photos, I want to upload the photos to a **private bucket on s3** and view those by **URLs saved on my server**. Can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "access it from an Android app"? What will the app be doing? Will users of the app be accessing the data in Amazon S3, or is this merely some data that you wish to provide to the app itself (eg a configuration file)? Do you want this file to be publicly accessible to anyone on the Internet, or only from the app? Feel free to edit your Question to provide additional information — the more details you can provide, the more likely you will receive a useful Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Restrict access to IAM role for S3 bucket. Use this role in Android App.

Answer (score 1):

The normal architecture for this is:

- Keep the Amazon S3 bucket **private** (no Bucket Policy)
- Users of the Android app provide their login information to the app, which **authenticates against your back-end service**
- Once authenticated, your back-end service can **generate temporary credentials using AWS Security Token Service (STS)** — permissions are assigned to these credentials that grant access to Amazon S3 (eg only for a certain path within a particular bucket)
- The mobile app can then use these temporary credentials to **directly communicate with Amazon S3** to upload/download objects

You could use **Amazon Cognito** for authentication and provisioning of credentials, or you could code your own authentication process (eg checking against your own database).

References:

- [Using Amazon Cognito for Mobile Apps - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html)
- [AWS IAM Now Supports Amazon, Facebook, and Google Identity Federation | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-iam-now-supports-amazon-facebook-and-google-identity-federation/)
- [About SAML 2.0-based Federation - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html)

If you only wish to **view photos**, then a simpler method would be for the back-end to generate **Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs**, which permit time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this both by:

1. creating a bucket policy for specific IAM user
2. creating an ACL policy for an account and then delegating permissions to a specific user